# How to make `docker run` inherit ulimits

Tags: linux, docker, ulimit

Running a command via docker does not seem to adhere to my currently configured `ulimit`s:

```
$ ulimit -t
5
~ $ sudo -- bash -c "ulimit -t"
5
~ $ sudo -- docker run --rm debian:wheezy bash -c "ulimit -t"
unlimited
```

How can I make it do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can set global limits in the Docker daemon config. On Ubuntu, this is managed in Upstart. Add `limit cpu <softlimit> <hardlimit>` to `/etc/init/docker.conf` and restart the daemon.

On a per container basis, you must use the `--privileged` flag with `docker run` in order to set ulimits. AFAIK there is no way to do it without `--privileged`.

See also [Runtime constraints on CPU and memory](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-cpu-and-memory).

Comment: Just checking: This then applies to all containers? In my case, I’d like to make per-instance-restrictions.

Comment: Updated my answer to include `--privileged`

Answer (score 0):

Currently (v1.5.0) these limits are inherited from the docker daemon's limits. But docker team is about to release [limits per containers](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9437).

For a workaround you can set the limits inside the container like

```
# docker run ubuntu bash -c "ulimit -t 5; doSomething"
```