# Elasticsearch fails to start on AWS kubernetes cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am running my kubernetes cluster on AWS EKS which runs kubernetes 1.10. 
I am following this guide to deploy elasticsearch in my Cluster 
[elasticsearch Kubernetes](https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster)

The first time I deployed it everything worked fine. Now, When I redeploy it gives me the following error.

```
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2018-08-24T18:07:28,448][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-master-6987757898-5pzz9] stopping ...
[2018-08-24T18:07:28,534][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-master-6987757898-5pzz9] stopped
[2018-08-24T18:07:28,534][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-master-6987757898-5pzz9] closing ...
[2018-08-24T18:07:28,555][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [es-master-6987757898-5pzz9] closed
```

Here is my deployment file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: es-master
  labels:
    component: elasticsearch
    role: master
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: elasticsearch
        role: master
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-sysctl
        image: busybox:1.27.2
        command:
        - sysctl
        - -w
        - vm.max_map_count=262144
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      containers:
      - name: es-master
        image: quay.io/pires/docker-elasticsearch-kubernetes:6.3.2
        env:
        - name: NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: CLUSTER_NAME
          value: myesdb
        - name: NUMBER_OF_MASTERS
          value: "2"
        - name: NODE_MASTER
          value: "true"
        - name: NODE_INGEST
          value: "false"
        - name: NODE_DATA
          value: "false"
        - name: HTTP_ENABLE
          value: "false"
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
        - name: NETWORK_HOST
          value: "0.0.0.0"
        - name: PROCESSORS
          valueFrom:
            resourceFieldRef:
              resource: limits.cpu
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 0.25
          limits:
            cpu: 1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: transport
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /data
      volumes:
          - emptyDir:
              medium: ""
            name: "storage"
```

I have seen a lot of posts talking about increasing the value but I am not sure how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the values in `/etc/security/limits.conf`? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272026/how-can-i-test-all-ulimits-of-docker) the docker daemon inherits any limits defined when the daemon started, so if that file is set too low, the simple answer might be to edit `limits.conf` and restart `docker`

Comment: I think I have to do it during runtime since I am running it in my kubernetes cluster and the pods are not persistent.

Comment: How do I edit my deployment.yaml above so that I can increase the max file descriptors during deployment ?

Comment: I think you overlooked my question: **what are the values in `limits.conf`** on the Node (not in the container, but on the Node)? The Node is where the docker daemon lives, and thus it is the one controlled by limits.conf

Comment: It was an issue with the AWS AMI that creates the EKS worker nodes. I had to do a sed -i -e 's/1024:4096/65536:65536/g' /etc/sysconfig/docker on each node and restart it to get it working. https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster/issues/215

Comment: I am also getting this issue however /etc/sysconfig/docker contents have changed since your post so I'm not sure your fix works.

Comment: After much Googling I found this issue in Amazons github issues https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/193

Comment: The OPTIONS="" is missing in latest AMI after it was removed in this PR. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/pull/186/files

Comment: Here is the solution - https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster/issues/215

Comment: That solution no longer works with latest EKS worker AMIs

Answer (score 1):

Just want to append to [this issue](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/193):

If you create EKS cluster by [eksctl](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl) then you can append to NodeGroup creation yaml:

```
 preBootstrapCommand:
      - "sed -i -e 's/1024:4096/65536:65536/g' /etc/sysconfig/docker"
      - "systemctl restart docker"
```

This will solve the problem for newly created cluster by fixing docker daemon config.

Answer (score 0):

Update default-ulimit parameter in the file '/etc/docker/daemon.json'

```
  "default-ulimits": {
    "nofile": {
      "Name": "nofile",
      "Soft": 65536,
      "Hard": 65536
    }
  }
```

and restart docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing that worked for me using EKS setting up an EFK stack.  Add this to your nodegroup creation YAML file under `nodeGroups:`.  Then create your nodegroup and apply your ES pods on it.

```
preBootstrapCommands:
  - "sysctl -w  vm.max_map_count=262144"
  - "systemctl restart docker"
```